# Make a function return itself after doing some work

Tags: ocaml

```ml
let log x = print_int x; log ;;

log 111 222;;
```

I am expecting `log` to print `111` and return itself and then print `222` on the second call but it does not work as expected, I am getting an error message instead. Why? How to make it work as expected?

I also tried `rec` to no avail.

```
File "./hello.ml", line 3, characters 8-11:
3 | log 111 222;;
            ^^^
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
         float
```

Answer (score 8):

If you try this:

```
let log x = print_int x; log
```

You're returning the `log` that already exists, which has type `float -> float`, thus the type mismatch.

If you try:

```
let rec log x = print_int x; log
```

The type system is getting confused. Your `log` is taking an `int` and returning... a function that takes an `int` and returns a function that takes an `int` and returns...

This recursiveness doesn't work.

... Unless you enable recursive types.

```
% ocaml -rectypes
OCaml version 4.14.0
Enter #help;; for help.

# let rec log x = print_int x; log;;
val log : int -> 'a as 'a = <fun>
# log 222 111;;
222111- : int -> 'a as 'a = <fun>
```

Associativity note: similar to the was `as` works in pattern-matching, here it grabs everything to the left, so `int -> 'a as 'a` reads as `(int -> 'a) as 'a` rather than `int -> ('a as 'a)`.

Answers to the [OP's next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74143973/what-are-the-tradeoffs-of-using-rectypes) detail why this option is not on by default.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you declare `log` as recursive, its return value will be some other function, the previous definition of `log`. And, indeed, `log` is a function that takes a floating value and returns a floating value.

If you do declare `log` as recursive, you will have further problems. In particular, your function will have a recursive type. You can get this to work using the `-rectypes` flag.

(I would explain more fully, but @Chris has given a good explanation while I was writing this.)